# Get City Name Using Lat and Long

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to get city name using latitude and longitude. I fetched latitude and longitude using the code.

```
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
```

Here I got both latitude and longitude. The I am using Google Map API http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true&key=YOUR_KEY. But I need `HTTPS` it seems. Is there is any way I could use it with `HTTP` from my localhost

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the docs:

[Best Practices Using Google Maps APIs Web Services](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/web-service-best-practices#SSL)

> **SSL Access**
>
> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/service/output?parameters
>
> HTTPS is required for all Maps API web service requests containing user data, or developer identifiers. Requests made over HTTP that include sensitive data may be rejected.

So, the answer to your question:

> Is there is any way I could use it with HTTP from my localhost

This not possible, as an HTTP request to the API will most probably be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to use some simple method to access localhost with https like ngrok

https://nullcast.io/how-to-forward-localhost-to-any-device-for-testing-ngrok/